# How much time does Google take to display rich snippet of a web page?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have put some Event rich snippet on the [web page](https://www.dezyre.com/Hadoop-Training-online/19), and Google has already crawled this page(as I knew it from the Google Cached Timing of this page), but Google is now showing the Event Rich Snippet.

Although when I have tested this page on [Structure data testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), I found no error there.

So, I want to know that does Google take some time to display the rich snippet after crawling a web page?

Could anybody help me to find out what is the problem with this page, so that the Rich Snippet is not being displayed properly on Google Search.

Comment: Sorry but there is already a handful of questions and answers regarding this subject on Pro Webmasters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking a for a approximate timeframe your going to be disappointed, there is no such timeframe and varies from site to site. Generally it takes anywhere between 2-12 weeks depending on the many factors. It should also be noted that Google can decide 'NOT' to display your rich data in search results.

***Having Rich Data on your website isn't always a golden ticket to richer search results, it varies from site to site, and niche to niche.***

> [SOURCE](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-rich-snippets)
>
> Q: How long does it take for rich snippets to be visible? A: Once
>   you've marked up your site's content, Google will discover it the next
>   time we crawl your site (although it may take some time for rich
>   snippets to appear in search results, if we do choose to display rich
>   snippets for your site). If you're marking up your content for rich
>   snippets, you can let us know. Google won't be able to individually
>   reply to your message, but we may use the information you supply to
>   improve our detection and display of marked-up content.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Your answer helped me to resolved my issue.